# Do not show iframe when errors occur

Tags: javascript, vimeo

We have integrated "Vimeo pro" videos in an important Italian institutional site, but we have a big problem.

If some videos are not available for any reason (connection errors, no video available, privacy restrictions, unsupported browser etc.) we would not like to see Vimeo error messages ("sorry","Uh oh!", "D'Oh" ecc.), but we have the necessity to completely hide the video.

Looking at javascript API we found we can listen to the "Ready" event and only if it occurs actually show the video iframe.
Is this the best solution?
Does this solution cover all error cases?

Or are there other ways to achieve the wanted behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you request the embed code dynamically (using oEmbed or our API) you can discover the status of the video before embedding it for your user.

- **API:** https://developer.vimeo.com/api
- **oEmbed:** https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed

Comment: We already do, but this not cover all error cases. For example if the client browser have flash disabled and is not HTML5 video compatible the iframe appear with funny error. In this case the video status is OK but the error is caused by something else.

Comment: Incompatibility with the user's browser is something that could be checked and acted upon from the domain itself. Using plain jQuery to access the iframe seems to be quite troublesome in this case.